# How do i make a layer PUSH layers below?

Tags: jquery, css

im in the midst of building a website, and i ran into this structural problem and i think im going to need a little help here.

the basic structure is this :

```
 <html>
<head>
<body>
<p class="skip">
<div class="container fixed_header ">
<div class="fluid_container">
<div class="body main">

</body>
</html>
```

you can check my website for more information if you need exact structure of my website :http://xestudio.xco.kr/ (it's safe from malware if your extension adblock blocks you from entering)

Now, the container is the main navigation div,
and the fluid_container is the image slider.
the body main is then of course the body.

I created this function that if i click on the toggle button,
it toggles the image slider to open and close. (if you click on the cog button on the leftside of my website, you can see the toggle switch)

what i was trying to make out of it originally is that when i click on the toggle button, it should completely hide the image slider and push the content upward so that the .body main takes the place of where the slider was.

But as you can see, all i see is white space that was underneath the image slider.

I think it's because the image slider and the .body main were overlapping each other in the first place.

Is there anyway I can make the slider take place in the document so that the image slider actually 'pushes' the .body main below?

and same goes to the menu bar (.container)

and here are the css codes.

```
.fluid_container {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.fluid_container.hide {
height: 0;
}


.body{background-color: #fff;
 position:relative;
padding:30px 0}
```

And the toggle switch function -

```
 <div class="switch">
  <input id="cmn-toggle-1" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round"     type="checkbox" checked>
  <label for="cmn-toggle-1"></label>
</div>


  <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.cmn-toggle').on('click',function(){
jQuery('.fluid_container').toggleClass('hide',200);

});});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why `height` is set to be zero ? `display : none` , and `display:block` is enough to hide and show

Comment: It's because it stutters, and quite visually messing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this css...

```
.fluid_container {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.hide {
display: none;
height: 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for that, but i must not use display. and this answer is actually quite off the topic. but appreciated as always.

Comment: ok so i might be didn't understand what you want. :)
Try `visibility: hidden;` `font-size: 0px;` etc Other options for hide content.

Comment: Okay, so the basic idea is that the slider must PUSH other elments. setting it invisible leaves white space, and it would not be something that i want. but thanks.

Comment: `visibility: hidden;` make white pace so it can be use.